# Add JavaScript to Geckofx 45

Tags: javascript, winforms, geckofx

I would like to know how can I add JavaScript in the HEAD section of my webpage. I'm using Geckofx 45 to render the page in my Windows Forms App.

This is what I have done so far, but it seems not to work.

```
GeckoHtmlElement headElement = Navegador.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
GeckoHtmlElement scriptElement = Navegador.Document.CreateHtmlElement("script");
scriptElement.TextContent = "('#test').on('submit',(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ url: 'test.php', type: 'POST', data: new FormData(this),  contentType: false, cache: false, processData: false, success: function(data){ $('#ajax_response').html(data); },  error: function() { } }); }));";
headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement);
```

Any idea what might been missing?.
The form with ID test is already in the webpage but I what to add the JavaScript in the DocumentCompleted event.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? No Javascript is output? The wrong Javascript is output? You get an exception? Something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. The problem is that I added a event listener when I click the submit button of the form, the ajax call doesn't work. It should fill in a div with id=ajax_response but its empty when I click the button. So that means that the JavaScript is not inside the HEAD section.

Comment: Can't you inspect the HTML? And have you checked the Ajax call is actually being made and responding correctly, using Fiddler or similar?

Comment: If I put the JavaScript code inside the webpage and I press the button it correctly fill in the ajax_response div. But when I add the JavaScript by code in the Win Forms it doesn't work. That tells me that the JavaScript code it is not being added to the current webpage.